# What is port used by GPS sensor that comes in tablet?

Tags: gps, windows-8, vb, tablet

Wanted to see: what is the port used by the GPS sensor that comes in a tablet?
or I can get the GPS?

In a tablet with Windows 8.1
What I want is to get by vb code, the coordinates of my location, using the GPS sensor of the tablet.

Comment: The question in it's current state is not answerable. What tablet are you referring to?  Are you talking about an Android Tablet? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: hi.  It is in a tablet with Windows 8.1
What I want is to get by vb code, the coordinates of my location, using the GPS sensor of the tablet

Comment: What have you tried so far? where are you stuck? Generally if you share your research, people will be more willing to help you out.

Comment: And you probably meant VB.NET, not vb right?

Comment: I'm working on vb.net.
Internet found a geolocation api w3c html code. Accomplish call this html code for vb. But I have a problem because I do not get the coordinates, I think it is html code that requires user permission. And I failed as putting that permission in the code. And now I try to get to the GPS sensor port.

Comment: the Web Geolocation API works only in the browser.  you need something like: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd464636(v=vs.85).aspx